# computing base class parameters from derived class

Tags: class, scala, parameters, radix

I have the following problem (programming language: scala):
A derived class D must compute base class parameters with a somewhat lengthy computation
from its own parameters:

```
class D(a:Int,b:Int) extends B(f(a,b)) {...}
```

Now I seem to have 3 possibilities:

(a) put the body of f(a,b) directly in the constructor of B: B({...})

(b) define f as a static function in the companion object of D

(c) define f as a member function of D which happens to be static

(a) Seems to be very inelegant.
Are these approaches even legal?
What would you do?

I am asking the question since I am  starting out with scala and our organisation does not actually have scala installed yet so I can do experiments only intermittently at home.

Thanks for all replies.

Comment: I'll go with (b) but IHMO this kind of question is better on 'code review' than SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `apply` method in the companion object which transform constructor params in appropriate way

```
object B {
  def f(a: Int) = a

  def apply(a: Int, b: Int) = new B(f(a), f(b))
}
```

If you need always transform constructor arguments think about correctness of your API. I suppose code review helps to make this code better.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a) if I didn't need to reuse the function elsewhere. The function has to go somewhere, why not where it's actually being used? But this is mostly an aesthetic choice; b) is fine too. If it's a function that needs to be called from elsewhere then I'd go with b). I wouldn't use c); whether or not it's legal it's certainly misleading and likely to cause maintenance problems when a future editor assumes this is a normal member function.